# PL/SQL procedure call works in an anonymous procedure, but not a stored one

Tags: plsql

I am logged in as a user other than "dbdesign". While I am logged in, the following code works in my program (anonymous procedure):

```
BEGIN
  dbdesign.pkg_developer_utils.create_schema_synonyms('MYSCHEMA');
END;
```

The following code does not work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE regenerate_synonyms AS
BEGIN
  dbdesign.pkg_developer_utils.create_schema_synonyms('MYSCHEMA');
END;
```

It gives me the following error:

> PLS-00201: identifier 'DBDESIGN.PKG_DEVELOPER_UTILS' must be declared

Why does this code work in an anonymous procedure, but give this error in a stored one?

Comment: Are you logged in as the dbdesign user when creating the procedure?

Comment: No. Is that significant, regarding why I cannot consistently access this procedure?

Comment: Oh, you said you're logged in as a user other than dbdesign when running the anonymous block, too. I thought it might be a grant issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to be a typo in your code. The message says:

```
DBDESIGN_PKG_DEVELOPER_UTILS
```

and not

```
DBDESIGN.PKG_DEVELOPER_UTILS
```

Comment: You are correct; this was a transcription error on my part, though.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?